# Create a dict (dictionary) from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a string.
The string is =

```
              """SSID 1                  : Something    
                 Network type            : Infrastructure    
                 Authentication          : WPA2-Personal    
                 Encryption              : CCMP"""
```

And i want the output as

```
{"ssid 1": "something", "Network type" : "Infrastructure", "Authentication": "WPA2-Personal", "Encryption": "CCMP"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
output = {}
for entry in input.split("\n"):
    tokens = [token.strip() for token in entry.split(":")]
    output[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]
```

Note that if you have a `:` in any of the keys or values this will break, but for the very simple example you provided I think it'll work.

Comment: You could split by ` : ` to make it less probable and use a dict comprehension instead. Nevertheless, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict comprehension like so

```
data = """
SSID 1                  : Something    
Network type            : Infrastructure    
Authentication          : WPA2-Personal    
Encryption              : CCMP"""

dct = {key: value
       for line in data.split("\n") if line
       for splitted in [line.split(" : ")] if len(splitted) == 2
       for key, value in [map(str.strip, splitted)]}

print(dct)
```

This yields

```
{'SSID 1': 'Something', 'Network type': 'Infrastructure', 
 'Authentication': 'WPA2-Personal', 'Encryption': 'CCMP'}
```